# repeater inside dynamic control losing items

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater inside a dynamic control, I am trying to get the items of the repeater in a postback prior to databinding.  This seems to work when I have a static repeater where the items are still intact, but when my repeater is inside a dynamic control and I try to get "repeater.Items", the count is always 0.

Is this normal behavior for repeaters when being placed inside a dynamic control?

Answer (score 0):

It is normal.  Viewstate is not restored in dynamically created controls.  Have a look at this article: [How to: Add Controls to an ASP.NET Web Page Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx)